# Component not rendering after using <Link> on click

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, components, react-router-dom

I am new with React JS so I am sorry if this problem seems trivial.

I have set up a `<Switch>` along with a number of `Routes` in App.js to redirect and link components together. The first `<Redirect>` from App.js goes to `ComponentA` where when a div is clicked, it should go to `ComponentB`, but that is not the case. After some fiddling, I could get `ComponentB` to render but it was ALONG with `ComponentA`, and now with more changes, nothing shows up except the header `.../componentB`.

**App.js**

```
import { ComponentA, ComponentB } from './components/Component.js';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Redirect, Switch} from 'react-router-dom';

function App() {
  const [isLoggedIn, setIsLoggedIn] = useState(false);
  
  return (
    <div>
      <Router exact path="/">
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/componentA" component={ComponentA}/>
          <Route exact path="/componentB" component={ComponentB}/>      
          <Route exact path="/componentC" component={ComponentC}/>  
        </Switch>  
        {isLoggedIn ? <Redirect to="/componentA"/> : <Redirect to="/componentC"/>}
        // componentC is irrelevant to the question
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**ComponentA**

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Redirect, Switch} from 'react-router-dom';

function ComponentA() {  
  return (
    <div>
      <Router exact path="/">
        // ... code
        <Link exact to="/componentB">
           <div></div>
        </Link>
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**ComponentB** (in the same file as ComponentA)

```
function ComponentB() {
  return (
    <div>Welcome to ComponentB</div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issue

I think the second `Router` component rendered in `ComponentA` is jacking the link navigation. This "inner" routing context handles the navigation request and updates the URL in the address bar but doesn't allow the "outer" routing context to see the change and update the `Route` that is matched and rendered.

## Solution

Remove the `Router` in `ComponentA`, also remove the `exact` prop from the `Link` as it's not a link prop.

```
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

function App() {  
  return (
    <div>
      // ... code
      <Link to="/componentB">
        <div></div>
      </Link>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Remove the `exact` and `path` props from `Router`, these are props for `Route` components.

```
import { ComponentA, ComponentB } from './components/Component.js';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Redirect, Switch} from 'react-router-dom';

function App() {
  const [isLoggedIn, setIsLoggedIn] = useState(false);
  
  return (
    <div>
      <Router>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/componentA" component={ComponentA}/>
          <Route exact path="/componentB" component={ComponentB}/>      
          <Route exact path="/componentC" component={ComponentC}/>  
        </Switch>  
        {isLoggedIn ? <Redirect to="/componentA"/> : <Redirect to="/componentC"/>}
        // componentC is irrelevant to the question
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}
```

## Update

You need only one routing context for your application, typically a `Router` that wraps `App` component. Comb your code for any other nested `Router` components and remove them as these will mess with navigation as explained above.

Comment: okay so apparently, when I click on it the first time, there is nothing but once I go back and then click again, I can view everything. Any logical explanation for this behaviour?

Comment: @ShlokJain If you're still having issues getting these components and links to work then I invite you to try creating a *running* codesandbox that reproduces the navigation issue and I can take a better look.

Comment: no no, I looked at the entire module and found out that, I was declaring another `<Router>` in ComponentC. Ironic huh (the process leading to Component A/B is through C as well)

Comment: Although I actually had a doubt, so in ComponentB, I show individual "posts", now if I declare my route earlier in the Web App, would I not be able to add an id in the header of the route?

Comment: @ShlokJain I think so long as the `Route` for *that* path is still mounted then it can be matched and rendered. Do you have an example of the route and path, and how you link to it with an `id`?

Comment: no I haven't programmed it yet, but I was intrigued as to if this problem would even arise